# ERROR IN processing.run('qgis:countpointsinpolygon',XXX)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqt5

When I tried to write a python script to run **Count points in polygon** (https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/countpointsinpolygon.html) in QGIS, I received the following message:

```
import processing
Result = "D:\aaaaa\DT\temp\saved_output.shp"
layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("UCL Main Campus")[0]
layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Listed_Building")[0]
layer_3 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Count")[0]
processing.run('qgis:countpointsinpolygon', layer_1, layer_2, 'NUMPOINTS', layer_3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 105, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "D:/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 132, in runAlgorithm
    if context.feedback() is None:
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'feedback'
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to execute this function successfully in QGIS 3?

---

Updated on 10 July 2019

I modified my code to the following:

```
import processing
layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("UCL Main Campus")[0]
layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Listed_Building")[0]
Result = "D:\aaaaa\DT\temp\saved_output.shp"
processing.run('qgis:countpointsinpolygon', {'FIELD' : 'NUMPOINTS', 'OUTPUT' : Result, 'POINTS' : layer_2, 'POLYGONS' : layer_1})
```

However, I still received the error message showing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QGIS 3.6\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 105, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "D:/QGIS 3.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 183, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

[image]

Comment: There is an error in your code. Use forwarded slashes instead of backshlashes in your path or use a preceding r, like r"\path\to\file"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is caused by a bug or bad documentation, but here is how i got it to work:

EDIT: modified for your data
EDIT2: correct windows path

```
import processing
layer_1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("UCL Main Campus")[0]
layer_2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Listed_Building")[0]
Result = "D:\\aaaaa\\DT\\temp\\saved_output.shp"
processing.run('qgis:countpointsinpolygon', {'FIELD' : 'NUMPOINTS', 'OUTPUT' : Result, 'POINTS' : layer_2, 'POLYGONS' : layer_1})
```

Note that you have to load the created layer manually after the operation completes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I copied your code and run in the python console, but I still got some error message. (I edited my question and added some screenshots of the new error.). Do you know how to solve this problem? May I ask where did you run the python script?

Comment: I tested on QGIS 3.4.6 on an Ubuntu machine with a point and polygon layer. probably the error is caused by the comment of Andreas Muller below your original post and has to do with Windows paths that are slightly different